# Slimbox loading images from javascript help?

Tags: javascript, ajax, load, lightbox, slimbox

I have literally looked everything up online, with no success, so now I am turning to those who know exactly what they are doing.

I am loading images from facebook, using a nice little tool that utulises jQuery to load up images from a certain album on a fan page.

Here is the page that I am currently working on: http://www.sfssc.ca/houstonwehaveaproblem.html

My problem, is that I cannot get the images on the bottom of the page to work with slimbox.

The script for this is

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
var AlbumID = "163187497033669";
var graph = "https://graph.facebook.com/" + AlbumID + "/photos?callback=?";
jQuery.getJSON(graph, function(data) {
var albumItem = [];
for(var key in data){
for(var key2 in data[key]){
val2=data[key][key2];
if(typeof(val2.source)!="undefined"){
albumItem.push(
'<li><a class="imageLink" rel="lightbox" href="' + val2.source + '" ><img src="' + val2.picture + '"/></a></li>'
);
};
};
};
jQuery('<ul />', {
'class': 'album',
html: albumItem.join('')
}).appendTo('#FBalbum');
});
});

</script>
```

The only changes I have done to this script, is that I added rel="lightbox" to the 12th line. When I did research, my best educated guess was that it was what is a command called Ajax, and Slimbox needed to be reloaded. Although this could be 100% wrong.

If anyone could help me with this, it would be greatly appreciated. All I need is to be able to use slimbox with these images loaded.

Thank you, 
Simon

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have just included the slimbox JS  file. It will not work as the DOM does not have the images when slimbox is loaded because they are added afterwards and slimbox only works for links which are ALREADY present when function is called.

It's simple to achieve what you are saying by a little modification to slimbox.js. You'll find this at the bottom of slimbox.js:

```
// AUTOLOAD CODE BLOCK (MAY BE CHANGED OR REMOVED)
if (!/android|iphone|ipod|series60|symbian|windows ce|blackberry/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
    jQuery(function($) {
        $("a[rel^='lightbox']").slimbox({/* Put custom options here */}, null, function(el) {
            return (this == el) || ((this.rel.length > 8) && (this.rel == el.rel));
        });
    });
}
```

Wrap it inside a function and just call it whenever you dynamically change DOM (after you append images). Change above code to this:

```
function loadsb(){
if (!/android|iphone|ipod|series60|symbian|windows ce|blackberry/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
            $("a[rel^='lightbox']").slimbox({/* Put custom options here */}, null, function(el) {
            return (this == el) || ((this.rel.length > 8) && (this.rel == el.rel));
        });
} }
```

Call `loadsb()` after `appendTo('#FBalbum');`

**EDIT**: Since you are having troubles let me make it even easier.

Use this as your `slimbox.js`: http://pastebin.com/8iye0PEB . I've removed the function declaration from that file, will add it to the JS on main page.

Now I see from your included JS, the Jquery object is not referenced by `$` , it is referenced by jQuery. so now your main page JS will be:

```
<script>
//Function to load SlimBox. PS: I'm refrencing the jQuery object by "jQuery" and not $ sign because of your markup
function loadsb(){
if (!/android|iphone|ipod|series60|symbian|windows ce|blackberry/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
            jQuery("a[rel^='lightbox']").slimbox({/* Put custom options here */}, null, function(el) {
            return (this == el) || ((this.rel.length > 8) && (this.rel == el.rel));
        });
} }

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
var AlbumID = "163187497033669";
var graph = "https://graph.facebook.com/" + AlbumID + "/photos?callback=?";
jQuery.getJSON(graph, function(data) {
var albumItem = [];
for(var key in data){
for(var key2 in data[key]){
val2=data[key][key2];
if(typeof(val2.source)!="undefined"){
albumItem.push(
'<li><a class="imageLink" rel="lightbox" href="' + val2.source + '" ><img src="' + val2.picture + '"/></a></li>'
);
};
};
};
jQuery('<ul />', {
'class': 'album',
html: albumItem.join('')
}).appendTo('#FBalbum');
//Let's now call the function we created above
loadsb();
//Slimbox is now loaded.
});
});

</script>
```

Also, please note: Now that we have to manually load slimbox, it will not work just by including the JS file in a page. you will have to use the Function declaration and call whenever you wanna load SB. (or just move the functon declaration to slimbox.js file and call it once in that file itself.)

Comment: Thanks @Abhinav Pandey, but this doesnt seem to be working, now even the html loaded image didnt work. I did as you said, replaced the code block with the one you displayed below and added to the html script loadsb() under appendTo('#FBalbum');, yet no success. Do you have any idea what might be wrong?

Comment: Probably because the jQuery object in your page is not handled by `$` sign. Anyways, I've edited my answer, read below the word Edit